# How to replace two terminal surface radiant with a 4 terminal of a cooktop

Tags: electrical, appliances, oven, electric-heat, cooktops

I have a  faulty surface radiant element that has two terminals as below:
[image]

The cooktop is Whirlpool Easytronic which shows "H" when it is hot.

The replacement for this faulty element is shown below as suggested by Whirlpool:

[image]

I have watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OexV6Btzejs&t=1s&ab_channel=PartsDr
and I am wondering how I can convert these two wire terminals to 4 wires. I assume I can safely ignore the lighting terminals (leave them without any wire/cover) as possibly my cooktop has another built-in mechanism to detect whether the surface is hot (show "H") or not as the original one does only have two wires.

**Update**: Thanks heaps for your questions.

1-Yes I am based in NZ

2-I swapped a working one and the one which was not working and turn the cooktop on and the replaced element was heating up, so I concluded that only the radiant element is faulty. Moreover, I can see the coil of the faulty element is disconnected. A close up of the faulty element:

[image]

3-My cooktop does not have the faulty element as I removed it. It is the bottom right element. For a test, I turn it on for a few seconds and turned it off again and now I can see H (I covered the wire of the removed element with tape for safety).This possibly can prove the hypothesis that our cooktop may have another mechanism to detect surface is still hot (maybe a timer). Please see this photo:

[image]

4- And the one with the red cross is the faulty one before removal.
[image]

5-model:
[image]

As identified by the supplier:Part #480121101515 HEATING ELEMENT 145MM  1200W

**Installed as follows:**

[image]

Comment: Did the new part come with an instruction leaflet?

Comment: If your original heating element only had two wires connecting to it, then it is reasonable to just connect those two wires to the corresponding labelled terminals on the new element and see how it works.  I can't see any point in covering the unused terminals.

Comment: How did you determine that the original element was faulty? Did you measure the resistance of the element? What did you get? Of course even if the heating element would give the expected resistance (approx range 10 ohm to 100 ohm) the limiter box could be at fault so the whole element should be replaced. But what I am getting at is the "infinite"  switch is also a possible failure point.

Comment: Care to edit to indicate brand/model numbers of all the parts invovled?

Comment: Since this is in NZ you have a simpler power system that we have in North America. I assume you have a neutral and a 230 or 240 V hot. This should make it easier to connect properly. Is this correct?

Comment: Does your existing unit have any markings on the terminals?

Comment: I see an "H" lower left, "S" upper left, "2" upper right. I would guess the hot from the switch goes to the H and the neutral goes to the connection on the side of the ceramic bowl. That should give you controlled heat. What you do with the others is a mystery to me. Two possibilities are, one, you leave them unconnected, and, two, you connect them to each other with a jumper.   The latter seems risky if you dont have instructions to do that.

Comment: Thanks Jim. The new one doesn't have any instruction as whirlpool spare part tokd me this. I haven't bought it yet. The photo is the one they emailed me.

Comment: Since you are in contact with Whirlpool, ask them about the fact that your stove only has two wires and the unit that they say is a replacement has connections for four.  A jumper may come with it or you may have to remove the jumper on the existing burner and transfer it to the new burner. I am sure that there is no timer. The hot warning uses the sensor in the element and the controls in the small box. Ask Whirlpool if a jumper comes with the new burner element.

Comment: Thanks Jim, will confirm this with them. If the hot warning is coming from the element sensor, how it shows hot when there is no element connected to those wires? As I explained I turned the switch of the removed element on for a few sec and then turned it off. After turning it off the sign switch to H.

Comment: In the burner that you removed there is a jumper wire that connects two contacts and presumably this powers the sensor. I don't have any idea why the Whirlpool approved substitute has a different number of connections. Maybe it can be used in different models what connect differently. Possibly you just connect the HOT wire from the switch and the neutral and that is it. My belief there is no timer is that a well designed appliance would directly measure the temperature rather than just use time. When used on low heat the HOT indicator should turn off sooner than when on high heat.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your time and the comments. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have amply confirmed that it is the burner that is at fault.

If Whirlpool tells you to use a replacement that has a different number of connections, then it is reasonable to take them at their word, but try to confirm that the part number is the correct one. You could ask them about what you are supposed to do about the difference in the number of connections, but if they won't tell you, then you could just connect the hot from the switch to the H and the neutral to the side of the ceramic bowl and see if if works.

Comment: Thanks Jim, upvoted, and confirm the output in a few weeks after installing the part. ETA is a few weeks